# Third section not on screen

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the code below. The window does not scroll to the third section. The code jumps from slide two to slide four. 
In my console log the data is correct 600, 1200, 1800 and 2400. 
I tried different things but the bug is still there.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body, html{margin:0;}
.slide{height: 600px;}
button{position:fixed; top:0; left:50%; margin-left:-32px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slide onscreen" style="background-color:#FFC000;"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-color:#FF4800;"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-color:#FFC480;"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-color:#AA4560;"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-color:#000000;"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="next()">volgende</button>


<script>
var section = document.getElementsByClassName("onscreen");

function next() {
  if (section[0].nextElementSibling) {
    section[0].nextElementSibling.className = "slide onscreen";
    section[0].className = "slide";
    var newTop = section[0].offsetTop;
    window.scrollBy(0, newTop);
    console.log(newTop);

  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These slides are all siblings. So offsetTop is going to be incrementally greater on each slide. Slide 1, 600px, slide 2, 1200px, and so on.  window.scrollBy scrolls to the windows current position + the amount given. So if you are at window.scrollY = 0, and pass 600, you'll be at window.scrollY = 600. When you pass 1200 on the next go round, you'll be at window.scrollY = 1800! So now it appears as if you've skipped over slide 3, because you scrolled 2x a slide's height.

Possible answer, if you don't want the challenge of figuring the rest out:

> If you have a hardcoded height for your slides, you could try passing a hardcoded scrollBy value as well. Or if you want to make your code a bit more flexible, you could query each slider for its height and pass that value instead. Then you can adjust your slide's height in css-land without breaking your js logic.

Comment: Ah ok, i did not know he summed up the value. i changed the function to "window.scrollTo()" now it's working :)

Comment: Joppieb wasn't summing the value. Each slide was further down the window, resulting in larger offsetTop values. Even still, window.scrollTo is a good solution =).